# Making case statements in Python

Tags: python

So I am trying to make a case statement for my python script to make it cleaner but there's no such thing (as far as I'm aware) so I have just made a bunch of if/else statements. Is there any way to make this cleaner?

```
if (config.dutCardTypes[0] in [6, 7]) and (config.isPrimary) and (config.measPwr):        ### Power Measurement for 28nm on Primary Only
  if dsppif[dutDevId].pifReadData(0x1e800) == 0x1 :
    print "Link Up, Measuring SteadyState Power..."
    if (("Sahara Validation" in dsppif[dutDevId].board.description)) :
        v, i, pwr = getOnBoardPwr(dsppif[dutDevId],"Sahara Validation")
        vdd21A_pwr = pwr["P2V1"]
        vdd12A_pwr = pwr["P1V2"]
        vdd_pwr    = pwr["VDD"]
        vdd3v3_pwr = pwr["P3V3"]
    elif "Athena" in dsppif[dutDevId].board.description:
        if (("Quad A" in dsppif[dutDevId].board.description)) :
            v, i, pwr = getOnBoardPwr(dsppif[dutDevId],"Athena Quad A")
            vdd21A_pwr = pwr["P2V1_A"] + pwr["P2V1_B"] + pwr["P2V1_C"] + pwr["P2V1_D"] + pwr["P2V1_E"]
            vdd12A_pwr = pwr["P1V2_A"] + pwr["P1V2_B"]
            vdd_pwr    = pwr["VDD"]
        elif (("Quad B" in dsppif[dutDevId].board.description)) :
            v, i, pwr = getOnBoardPwr(dsppif[dutDevId],"Athena Quad B")
            vdd21A_pwr = pwr["P2V1_A"] + pwr["P2V1_B"] + pwr["P2V1_C"] + pwr["P2V1_D"] + pwr["P2V1_E"]
            vdd12A_pwr = pwr["P1V2_A"] + pwr["P1V2_B"]
            vdd_pwr    = pwr["VDD"]
        elif (("Quad C" in dsppif[dutDevId].board.description)) :
            v, i, pwr = getOnBoardPwr(dsppif[dutDevId],"Athena Quad C")
            vdd21A_pwr = pwr["P2V1_A"] + pwr["P2V1_E"]
            vdd12A_pwr = pwr["P1V2_A"] 
            vdd_pwr    = pwr["VDD"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Comment: You can **1.** Fix your indentation **2.** Remove the unneeded parenthesis.

Comment: Dictionaries. Check more here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python

Comment: @leaf fixed indentation, sorry

Comment: @Billy how do I go about doing that in this block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a high level, python suggests that you try and use dictionaries for this kind of thing.
I won't try and translate your example, since it's a little verbose, but essentially instead of using a case statement like so:

```
function(argument){
    switch(argument) {
        case 0:
            return "zero";
        case 1:
            return "one";
        case 2:
            return "two";
        default:
            return "nothing";
    };
};
```

You can use a dictionary of possibilities like so

```
def numbers_to_strings(argument):
    switcher = {
        0: "zero",
        1: "one",
        2: "two",
    }
    return switcher.get(argument, "nothing")
```

You could also create a switcher class, and map your actions to your conditions. Overall the python way is to increase legibility.

Comment: Sorry but would you be able to just do 1 case as an example from my snippet? Im just having trouble following what exactly to do